# Select Your Provisional Moderators

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This community needs to contribute some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators, ASAP. **Most site have this discussion starting from the first days.** Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator:

- We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

  - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
  - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
  - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
  - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.
- Bonus points for:

  - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
  - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
  - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

#### Update

[Kosmonaut, mmyers, and nohat](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) have been appointed as provisional moderators.

Comment: Answers should be marked as community wiki to allow the nominees to edit even if their reputation is low.

Comment: Are there a lot of matters that have cropped up that need moderator attention? Why the rush (“ASAP”)? We seem to be a pretty slow-moving community and I fear the results of unnecessary hastiness.

Comment: @nohat: If no one is working on [these issues](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), this site isn't going to make it. Moderators head up this effort. Every other site had moderators at two weeks. Almost three weeks in, you haven't even had the *discussion.* [Here's](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72) the kind of things moderators should be working on and fixing [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/137).

Comment: @Robert now that I look around with an eye to it, there is quite a bit of moderator-only activity that is required. What criterion are you using as a threshold for when to grant interim moderator status?

Comment: @nohat: English.SE is past due so I will be selecting moderators in the next few days. There's no specific criteria in terms of "user must have X." I have to be conservative with my choices because, ideally, moderators should be elected, not appointed. Most of the traits I look for are outlined in these two articles: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/.

Comment: So, @Robert, how about it? There are good nominees and plenty of votes to help you decide.

Comment: I suggest that only up votes should be counted, instead of net votes, as in an election you vote *for* you preferred candidate and not *against* other candidates

Comment: @Midhat http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56904/allow-diamond-mods-to-lock-out-downvoting-to-support-poll-election-type-questio

Comment: @Michael Mrozek that link does not work

Comment: @Theta30 Well, not anymore; it was deleted a few months ago. It was a feature-request for the same thing Midhat was asking for

Answer (score 10):

I nominate [**nohat**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat) ([meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat)) — accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [**Kosmonaut**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/449/kosmonaut) ([meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/449/kosmonaut)) — accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate myself: [**mmyers**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/223/mmyers) ([meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/223/mmyers)).

This would most likely be a temporary situation until the actual moderator elections are held. I'm already a moderator on Stack Overflow, so that takes a fair amount of my time and will probably keep me from committing enough time here once the user base gets fairly large.

But on the other hand, I know the system and can help this site and the other moderators get off the ground.

Comment: As an active MSO participant, I __strongly__ support this.  (+1!)

Answer (score 4):

I nominate myself: **[kiamlaluno](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno)** ([meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno)).

Answer (score 3):

I nominate [**Vincent McNabb**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/140) ([meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140/vincent-mcnabb)).

Comment: Voting for Vincent based on the sentiment expressed in this question (http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/109/are-these-questions-real-or-fake/110#110)