# Tactical down votes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, votes

On [How to pronounce 'router'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/how-to-pronounce-router/2393#2393) my answer has been down voted from a user who answered to the same question, and who first commented my answer with a link to a link to a pronunciation file present in dictionary.com which should have been supposed to make me notice that I was wrong about the pronunciation (despite the fact another user commented on that saying that in American English the pronunciation is the same for both the meaning of *router*). To say it all, the pronunciation reported from dictionary.com (I am not sure if the pronunciation reported from that site is in American English, British English, or Australian English) is |ˈraʊtər| for *any of various tools or machines for routing, hollowing out, or furrowing*, and |ˈrutər, ˈraʊ-| for *a person or thing that routes*.
The comment has been then changed to

> Gee, I wonder if anyone else posted that information before you?

His reply didn't report what he found in the *New Oxford American Dictionary* or the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, but he thinks he gave the same information I gave.

I got 3 down votes in less than 2 minutes, and in all the cases for an answer where that same user answered.

As a final note, I find this comment [on another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/is-laid-down-a-proper-term/2394#2394) I wrote (which had a down vote too):

> kiamlaluno, why do you keep copying my answers to questions? This isn't funny any more.

I didn't copy his answer; that is clear to who reads both the answers.
What does that then mean? Can other users reply to a question where he already wrote his answer, or is that forbidden?

Let's then analyze the answers.

- His answer starts with *I believe the meaning*. I interpret it as meaning that he is not sure of what he is writing.
- His answer doesn't contain any reference to any dictionaries.
- I looked for *laid* on the NOAD, and the dictionary shown me the definition for *lay*; i looked for a phrase that was referring to a illness, and I found *lay [someone] low*.
- To verify which preposition should be used with *lay [someone] low*, I searched in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, and I found that the preposition used is *by*. I also noted that *lay [someone] low* was used in a sentence that was not referring to an illness, and I wrote that sentence.

The same thing happen on another [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/commentor-vs-commentator/2381#2381), where the same user down votes the answer given from another user because he feels like the answer is not useful. His answer starts with *My own feeling about this is that "commenter" is a new word*; is that more useful than the reply given from the other user?

The [down voting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-a-difference-between-frenchmen-and-french-men/2452#2452) still happens. Am I copying his answer also when he says that *French man* has the same meaning of *Frenchman*, and I report that they have two different meanings?

**Updated**

He says I copied one of his answers, but then he answers to a question, giving [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/is-correct-to-use-an-adjective-as-appositive/1212#1212) that is equivalent to [another one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/is-correct-to-use-an-adjective-as-appositive/1142#1142). If I give an answer that is different from his, I am copying his answer, but he can answer to a question saying what others has already said. Two different criteria are applied; the one pro his answer is not applied to others' answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That guy clearly has some kind of [beef](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/select-your-provisional-moderators/204#204) with you. Even before reading the exchanges you posted, I've gotten a negative vibe from this guy based on other questions/answers. I've noticed it ranges from a [condescending](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/suggestion-single-word-lookups-are-off-topic) [tone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/what-does-word-cinemaddict-mean/1856#1856) to downright combativeness.

I hadn't brought it up before because I think that sometimes intent or sarcasm gets lost in this medium, and I want to think that he doesn't mean for these to come off as harsh or lecturing as they appear on the site.

As to the tactical downvoting, that is very hard to prove, but his ratio of 138 upvotes/149 downvotes does indicate that he is more of a Simon than a Paula. =)

Comment: I don't think it's a coincidence that he wrote _Gee, I wonder if anyone else posted that information before you?_ right before my question was down voted. I also find boring that he says I copied his answer when it's not so.

Comment: I feel ya, but don't take it too personally. One person can only do so much damage since they can only vote down an answer once. In the end, rep amounts to little more than unicorn tears anyway.

Comment: JohnFx: Re your "beef" comment: there are three downvotes on kiamlaluno's proposal for moderator and one comment upvote on my downvote comment, so at least three people have a "beef" with him. I'd recommend taking a very hard look at this guy before offering him any more sympathy votes for his self-proposal as moderator. My downvote was made well before yesterday's question copying incident.

Comment: This remind me of the joke about the person who keep to say he was Napoleon. @JohnFX: It's not me to take it personally; it's him that has something against my person. The _I'd recommend taking a very hard look at this guy_ says it all. He wants to convince others I "copied" his answer to justify the fact he down voted a question just to keep his own question higher than others. The down vote for my proposal as moderator was made before, but the comment has been done right after the incident; does that mean anything?

Comment: Let's consider also when he wanted to tell me what I should say about the comment made from another user. Do I tell him what he must say in his comments? No. Shall I pretend he does the same? Yes.

Comment: Can we find a way to resolve this without it getting ugly? This community is too new and fragile to have feuds so early. I'll open another question on meta to discuss whether downvoting other people who give the same answer is acceptable if you can both live with whatever the community decides on that. Does that work?

Comment: I opened this question (http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-it-an-acceptable-practice-to-downvote-other-answers-that-are-too-similar-to-pr). Hopefully we can settle this peacefully.